# Using for loop to delete data in database

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I want to delete every item in the array from the database.

```
string[] ids = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(row => row["ProductID"].ToString())
    .ToArray();

for (int i = 0; i <= ids.Length; i++) {
    string val = ids[i];
    MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand();
    cmd1.CommandText = "Delete from tblindividualproduct where ProductID = @p1";
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", val);
}
```

When I run this the line

```
string val = ids[i];
```

gives me an error which says:

> Index was outside the bounds of the array.

What's wrong with this?

This is my whole code UPDATED

```
string connString = "Server=192.168.1.100;Database=product;Uid=newuser;Pwd=password";
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);

        string[] ids = dt.AsEnumerable()
                                .Select(row => row["ProductID"].ToString())
                                .ToArray();
        try
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand();
            conn.Open();
            cmd1.CommandText = "Delete from tblindividualproduct where ProductID = @p1";
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", "");
            for (int i = 0; i < ids.Length; i++)
            {
                string val = ids[i];
                cmd1.Parameters[0].Value = val;
                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Checkout Successful");
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays in .NET are zero based and thus the valid indexes go from zero to `length - 1`.
You should change your code to

```
   for (int i = 0; i < ids.Length; i++)
```

As pointed by other answer you loop also fails to call `cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery` and it seems that you don't have associated a connection to the MySqlCommand (thus it will not work at all).

An interesting variation on your code could be to create a single string with all of your commands and submit the command just one time.

**Beware that this is not recommended unless you are absolutely sure that your ID are just numbers and not coming from user input**

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i <= ids.Length; i++) 
   sb.AppendFormat("Delete from tblindividualproduct where ProductID = {0};", ids[i]);

MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand();
cmd1.CommandText = sb.ToString();
cmd1.Connection = connection;
cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 1):

Array indexes go from 0 up to `Length - 1`, so you need to stop the loop *before* `i == ids.Length`. Try replacing the `<=` with `<`. Also, don't forget to call [`ExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to execute your command.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ids.Length; i++) {
    string val = ids[i];
    MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(conn);
    cmd1.CommandText = "Delete from tblindividualproduct where ProductID = @p1";
    cmd1.Connection = conn;
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", val);
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

You can also set up the command outside of the loop and only set the parameter and execute the command inside the loop:

```
MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(conn);
cmd1.CommandText = "Delete from tblindividualproduct where ProductID = @p1";
cmd1.Connection = conn;
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", "");
for (int i = 0; i < ids.Length; i++) {
    string val = ids[i];
    cmd1.Parameters[0].Value = val;
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: i got error on `cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();` it says `Connection must be valid and open` but i just put `conn.Open()` right before the for loop

Comment: @Austria make sure you assign a valid connection to the command, usually done through the constructor of the command.

Comment: i just updated my whole code written above. Can you spot the wrong?

Comment: @MixAustria I had to step away. You've already accepted Steve's answer, but I've updated my for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

This will be much more efficient as there's only one call to the DB, plus there's no need anymore to iterate through yours `ids` collection.

```
string[] ids = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(row => row["ProductID"].ToString())
    .ToArray();

MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand();
cmd1.CommandText = "Delete from tblindividualproduct where ProductID IN (" + String.Join(",", ids) + ")";
```

Comment: Wrong, the parameter @p1 is considered a string and your command will be equal to `IN('1,2,3,4')` and no record will be deleted

Comment: Yes, better now, however I prefer to avoid IN because I am always not sure if MySql uses indexes in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Your index goes from 0 to your length -1 like this:

```
tring[] ids = dt.AsEnumerable()
                            .Select(row => row["ProductID"].ToString())
                            .ToArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < ids.Length; i++) {
        string val = ids[i];
        MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand();
        cmd1.CommandText = "Delete from tblindividualproduct where ProductID = @p1";
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", val);
    }
```

And **Index was outside the bounds of the array.** means that your accessed an element that does not exist with that index.